# Adding double quote delimiters into csv file

Tags: excel, csv, double-quotes

I have a number of text files which contain radio programme titles where each item is on a separate line, e.g.:

```
15 by 15
15 Minute Drama
Adrian Mole
Afternoon Drama
Afternoon Reading
etc
```

I would like to add double quotes as delimiters to each line, e.g.:

```
"15 by 15"
"15 Minute Drama"
"Adrian Mole"
"Afternoon Drama"
"Afternoon Reading"
etc
```

I thought I might be able to do this in Excel but not been able to find a way. I really don't mind whether the solution is Excel based or something else, as long as I don't have to do it manually.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If one of these solutions meets your needs, please kindly select one of the answers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy in Excel (or any spreadsheet application).

You'll want to use the `=CONCATENATE()` function as shown in the formula bar in the following screenshot:

Step 1 involves adding quotes in column B,

Step 2 involves specifying the function and then copying it down column C (by now your spreadsheet should look like the screenshot),

[image]

Step 3 (if you need the text outside of the formula) involves copying column C, right-clicking on column D, choosing Paste Special >> Paste Values. Column D should then contain the text that was calculated in column C.

Comment: This is not the solution, this is just a over-engineered work-around. @Manav provided one of the correct solution.

Comment: @Seymour Sweet, let me just open PowerShell on my Mac where I'm using Excel... Using a second program such as terminal/shell/etc to manipulate spreadsheet data after saving in Excel is not an ideal or efficient solution. The above approach within Excel is exactly how I addressed. Agree to disagree.

Comment: Then what? If you export as a CSV you end up with 3 double quotes at beginning and end.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey - The following discussion (I think) addresses your question (https://superuser.com/questions/349882/how-to-avoid-double-quotes-when-saving-excel-file-as-unicode). It looks like you would need to escape the double quotes with another set of double-quotes.

Comment: @joemienko that doesn't work, that's how you end up with 3 sets of quotes in the CSV. Using Powershell proved the useful solution. One way to use you solution is to copy/paste from Excel into a text file, but Excel apparently will never save the CSV with a single set of double quotes.

Comment: Not a solution for me either... as you would end up exporting your CSV with unwanted columns... So back to square one with hacking your export result with a text editor or other solutions...

Comment: This isn't vaguely a correct answer and doesn't solve the problem asked in the question

Answer (score 46):

Here's a way to do it without formulas or macros:

1. Save your CSV as Excel
2. Select any cells that might have commas
3. Open to the Format menu and click on Cells
4. Pick the Custom format
5. Enter this => \"@\"
6. Click OK
7. Save the file as CSV

(from http://www.lenashore.com/2012/04/how-to-add-quotes-to-your-cells-in-excel-automatically/)

Comment: This did not work for me. My file has long text fields with embedded commas. Using that format the long text no longer wraps within the cell width and consequently is displayed as a row of ####. When I followed the steps above, the resulting csv also, surprisingly, contains #### rather than the original text.

Comment: I used to use the concatenate solution. But this is much neater.

Comment: Also use \"#\" for numeric columns

Comment: This does not work as expected for Date or Numeric columns.

Comment: For quoted numerical values use `\"#\";\"#\";\"#\";\"@\"` (these are the formats for respectively positive, negative, zero and text). And for dates you just enter the wanted date format enclosed with escaped quotes: `\"d-m-yyyy\"`

Comment: For me this then saves as `""""Data"""",""""data2""""` which is what I see when opened in text editor.

Comment: This is not the solution, this is just a over-engineered work-around. @Manav provided one of the correct solution.

Comment: Not acceptable on Office 365, as it surrounds with triple-double quotes. 44000 ends up as `"""44000"""`. This is plainly ridiculous. Why on Earth would you want to triple your double quotes? The way I fixed this was then to use a text editor to replace `"""` with `"`

Comment: This solution is not the best. If you have empty string fields it will ignore the double quotes for those.

Answer (score 38):

open powershell and run below command:

```
import-csv C:\Users\Documents\Weekly_Status.csv | export-csv C:\Users\Documents\Weekly_Status2.csv  -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Excellent, i don't know why no upvotes for this, i literally wasted time righting code for doing this using nodejs

Comment: Who thanks mate this works perfect, saves me huge amount of time!

Comment: UP vote this answer because it is the correct solution.

Comment: This only adds double quotes at the start of initial cells and at the end of last cells. I have semicolon separated csv. Is it due to that? Is there anyone else experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Thank you so much, I've spent way too much time trying to solve this before seeing this answer. This was so easy and fixed my issue. :)

Comment: Well this is acceptable if you want to surround ALL fields with quotes, not specific ones...

Comment: This solution worked! Thank you! Note. Add a single quote (') before and after the path. Otherwise, you will get the following error: Import-Csv : Cannot bind parameter 'Delimiter'.

Comment: import-csv assumed that the first row to be headers which have to be unique values. If there are repeated values on the first row, import-csv will return an error: 'The member "<repeated_value>" is already present'.

Comment: Had an issue with using the path separator \. I just used the filename without the path on the same folder. I suspect using \\ or / might work? No it didn't, the error is export-csv : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Documents\test2.csv'.

Comment: Some command to use in UNIX systems?

Answer (score 4):

In Excel for Mac at least, you can do this by saving as "CSV for MS DOS" which adds double quotes for any field which needs them.

Comment: saving as "CSV for MS DOS" does not work on windows (i don't know why they have this option in windows save as dialog in office 365)

Comment: It... "sortof" works. In that it puts quotes around any text block segment that contains a comma.  Sadly, that's not as useful as you might like.

Comment: Any field *which needs them* - this is therefore not a solution when you want to export your CSV **with** double quotes around every field.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes can be achieved using VBA in one of two ways

First one is often the best

`"...text..." & Chr(34) & "...text..."`

Or the second one, which is more literal

`"...text..." & """" & "...text..."`

Comment: The second one can be condensed down as well, to `"...text...""...text..."` (note, no `&` needed in that one, although not as easy to debug)

Comment: Many thanks for response bmgh1985, I don't know how to use VBA, but the first solution offered does it for me. Thanks anyway! :-)