# Random data in ADF DataFlow Preview

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

The question title might sound vague, but that's because I have no idea what's happening in my adf dataflow.

I have a table called table A, when I preview Table A's data in ADF dataflow, I see some of the values spread out randomly.

For example, I have a Column "Name" that contains all string values and no numbers, but I see random numbers after a few rows. Those numbers do not exist like that in the source file.

here is what what I see. Those Highlighted numbers are not supposed to be there

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Usually happens if your source file is a delimited file(CSV), if yes, then check if you have some text data with the delimiter.

If yes again, then wrap them in a " " or change delimiter.
If it's not a CSV source then will need to further debug.

Comment: Hi, yes it is a Delimited CSV file. Could you please explain your steps further . How can I check if I have text data with the delimiter? i do already have in source settings quote character set to "double quote"

Comment: Ah cool, it's simple. You need to check the row before this incorrect data. Maybe one of the rows are cut off that's the one causing the problem.

Comment: To fix it as mentioned earlier, the best practice is to wrap it in double quotes in your source data set. If you have it wrapped in single quotes then the modify the Dataset property, quoteChar to '

Comment: yes, In the source file there is text data before those rows. What am I wrapping in "" ? (sorry super new to this whole thing)

Comment: It's no problem. Assume you have 4 columns and the fourth one is causing the issue for example like, (1, True, 400, Product A, Costs 2000$) then modify it to (1, True, 400, "Product A, Costs 2000$")

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i am not able to solve the probelm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239373/discussion-between-gumdrop-and-alex-rajan-samuel).

Comment: If your source file is provided by a different team ask them to wrap text fields in double quotes "". If you are doing this to learn then you can do any of the solutions in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25237847/adding-double-quote-delimiters-into-csv-file)

Comment: Hi, this solution hasnt worked. I still have the same problem

Comment: Did you get the CSV issue sorted out?

Comment: yes, I got them to take out the column altogether

Comment: What issue are you still facing?